# How to use join and order_by with multiple records in SQL/SQLalchemy?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlalchemy

I have 2 tables looks like this:

student_info:

```
| student_id | major |
|------------|-------|
| 1001       | CS    |
| 1002       | CS    |
| 1003       | CS    |
| 1004       | CS    |
| 1005       | BI    |
```

student_grade:

```
| student_id | course | semester    | grade |
|------------|--------|-------------|-------|
| 1001       | CS.201 | 2016.Spring | 100   |
| 1001       | CS.202 | 2016.Fall   | 90    |
| 1001       | EE.201 | 2016.Spring | 90    |
| 1002       | CS.201 | 2016.Spring | 70    |
| 1002       | CS.202 | 2016.Fall   | 70    |
| 1003       | CS.201 | 2016.Spring | 99    |
| 1003       | EE.201 | 2016.Fall   | 90    |
| 1003       | CS.202 | 2016.Fall   | 90    |
| 1004       | CS.201 | 2016.Spring | 99    |
| 1004       | BI.202 | 2016.Fall   | 80    |
| 1005       | CS.201 | 2017.Spring | 100   |
```

Now I want to select top 2 students major in `CS` grade of `CS.201` in `2016.Spring`, so the results may looks like this:

```
| student_id | major | semester    | course | grade |
|------------|-------|-------------|--------|-------|
| 1001       | CS    | 2016.Spring | CS.201 | 100   |
| 1003       | CS    | 2016.Spring | CS.201 | 99    |
| 1004       | CS    | 2016.Spring | CS.201 | 99    |
```

Note that since there're 2 students who got `99` in `CS.201`, so we want all 3 records (not just using `limit(2)`).

The database is MySQL.

My sql script look like :

```
SELECT student_info.student_id, 
               student_info.major, 
               student_grade.semester, 
               student_grade.course, 
               student_grade.grade
FROM student_info, student_grade
WHERE student_info.major = 'CS'
  AND student_info.student_id = student_grade.student_id
  AND student_grade.semester = '2016.Spring'
  AND student_grade.course = 'CS.201'
ORDER BY student_grade.grade DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: did you try anything yet, and if it didn't work, what error message did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question need to use `DENSE_RANK` function,unfortunately `DENSE_RANK` function only support version higher than *MySQL 8.0*.

You need to make the `rank` on `student_grade`,so you can write subquery to create rank result set, then `join` on `student_info`

```
SELECT b.student_id, 
       b.major, 
       a.semester, 
       a.course, 
       a.grade 
FROM   (SELECT student_id, 
               grade, 
               semester, 
               course, 
               @prev := @curr, 
               @curr := grade, 
               @rank := IF(@prev = @curr, @rank, @rank + 1) AS rank 
        FROM   student_grade, 
               (SELECT @curr := NULL, 
                       @prev := NULL, 
                       @rank := 0) s 
        WHERE  course = 'CS.201' 
               AND semester = '2016.Spring' 
        ORDER  BY grade DESC) a 
       INNER JOIN student_info b 
               ON a.student_id = b.student_id 
WHERE  a.rank <= 2 
       AND b.major = 'CS'
```

*sqlfiddle:https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tkU4UfRE3AZziiEn4HiLwF/0*

**Explanation:**

- `@prev := @curr` let `@curr` be previous grade
- `@curr := grade` set current grade in @curr variable
- `@rank := IF(@prev = @curr, @rank, @rank+1) AS rank` to check `@prev` variable  and `@curr` variable are the same.if they are same used same `rank` otherwise `rank + 1`

Comment: Thanks ! your script helps me a lot ! but what's the meaning of ` @prev := @curr ...` ? Is there any docs I can go further?

Comment: `@prev := @curr` can make sure the grade are the same then the same rank on  `@rank := IF(@prev = @curr, @rank, @rank+1) AS rank`  I add some Explanation on my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try mysql `window function` with `DENSE_RANK()`. You can refer documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_dense-rank).

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT
        a.*,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER w AS 'rank'
    FROM

    (
        SELECT
            g.student_id,
            i.major,
            g.course,
            g.semester,
            g.grade
        FROM 
            student_grade g
            JOIN student_info i
                ON i.student_id = g.student_id

        WHERE i.major = 'CS'
            AND g.semester = '2016.Spring'
            AND g.course = 'CS.201'
    ) a

    WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY a.grade DESC)
) b

WHERE b.rank <= 2;
```

Hope this help, good luck!

Comment: `DENSE_RANK` function only support version  higher than  MySQL 8.0

Comment: Thanks your nice script ! But I'm using sqlalchemy, there is no implementation of this function yet